# DRF ModelSerializer - How to add an additional field that is many primary keys?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a ModelSerializer named `ExampleModelCreateSerializer` accepting data for it's models fields. However, I would like to pass additional data that doesn't belong in the model. Specifically, I would like to include a list of primary keys of a different model. For that, I am using `serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)`

When I try to submit a POST request, I get this error. 
`` Got a `TypeError` when calling `examplemodel.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `examplemodel.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the ExampleModelCreateSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly. ``

I assume this is because of the additional field trying to be saved into the model instance. So I tried to pop the field right after the serializer runs is_valid.

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.validated_data.pop('listofkeys')
    ...
```

This returns `'examplemodel' object has no attribute 'listofkeys'`

All I am trying to do is pass additional fields to this Serializer and not have those fields conflict with the saving and creation of the model instances.

I've read in other answers to fairly similar questions to make these fields read-only but wouldn't that only work with GET requests? I need these additional fields to be submitted via POST and processed by the Serializer.

Note: The Serializer class is also extending WriteableNestedModelSerializer

Edit: Tried popping it in the serializer create but produces the same AttributeError

```
class ExampleModelCreateSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):

    listofkeys = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
            many=True,queryset=models.another_model.objects.all())

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...
        listofkeys = validated_data.pop('listofkeys')
        instance = super(ExampleModelCreateSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = example_model
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', ..., 'listofkeys', )
```

Comment: Show your complete serializer.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan updated for complete serializer